# How to fetch only active items from a Categories->Sources->News structure in Laravel?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, orm, eloquent

This is a rather simple requirement, but I'm not sure how to do it the Laravel way. I have a simple structure of categories, item sources and items and I need to fetch only the active items.

- *Categories*, eg. Tech, Science, Entertainment
- *Sources* (each source belongs to one category), eg. Engadget, Popular Science, Billboard
- *News* items from each source.

All of the above items can be set to active or inactive. If 'Tech' is set to inactive, I will only get news items from the other category sources, eg. Popular Science and Billboard.

A custom query will do this, but I want to know if there is a more eloquent [sic] way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Category model can have function that it **has many** Sources, let call it sources(). 
Sources model should function that it **has many** News: function news().
Then you can do something like that:

```
$news=App\Category::find($categoryID)->sources()->get()->news()->where('active',1)->get();
```

And if you want to get news only from active sources:

```
$news=App\Category::find($categoryID)->sources()->where('active',1)->get()->news()->where('active',1)->get();
```

Also you can make custom function in Category model like:

```
public function activeSources(){
    return App\Source::where('category_id',$this->id)->where('active',1)->get();
}
```

And then get news like that:

```
$news=App\Category::find($categoryID)->activeSources()->news()->get();
```

Comment: The last line seems to only find it for one category id. How do I run the query to get all active categories and then sources and so on?

Comment: To get all news from all categories and sources you can do this `$news=App\Category::all()->activeSources()->news()->get();` but I would recommend to to this: `$news=News::all()`

Comment: If you want to get "Source" object from "news", and "category" from "source". You should do functions in models **belongsTo** and use then like that: `$news=News::all();` then you use loop to take each news, and that individual object can link to parent `$obj->source()->get()`.